# Google Calendar Api: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine' - Works locally but not on server

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I am trying to use the Google Calendar API on my Web Application to create/update events.

Locally my application works flawlessly. All Google Calendar event creations and updates work as expected. When I try to deploy the exact same code onto the server and use it I get these three errors listed below in this exact order.

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'google.appengine'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'oauth2client'
ImportError: file_cache is unavailable when using oauth2client >= 4.0.0 or google-auth
```

Does anyone have any idea why these errors would be happening and how to fix them?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like `google.appengine` and `oauth2client` are not installed on the server.  Did you install them?

Comment: @JohnGordon google.appengine isn't explicitly installed locally or on the server but it works locally. oauth2client is installed on both.

Comment: Yes it is installed locally.  Perhaps someone other than yourself installed it?

Comment: Nope, no one else has touched this computer.

Comment: You said the code works locally.  Those packages _must_ be installed locally.

Comment: The pip freeze of both the virtual environment on the server and locally return the same packages so how could `google.appengine` be installed if it doesn't show up there?

Comment: Perhaps it wasn't installed by pip?  Try this code locally: `import google.appengine; print(google.appengine.__file__)` to see where it is installed.  That might give a clue _how_ it was installed.

Comment: When running it locally I get `ImportError: No module named google.appengine`

Comment: Are you sure the local code actually _uses_ that module?  Perhaps the code is aware that it's running locally, and uses some sort of mock version of that module instead of the real one?

Comment: Which GAE environment/runtime?

Comment: @DanCornilescu I'm not using GAE at all. Is it necessary to use GAE to add google calendar api to an existing web application running on an apache server? If so is there any documentation that states that? I couldn't seem to find any but Google's documentation hasn't been super helpful.

Comment: Oh, sorry, you tagged the post with GAE's tag. Never mind. You may be using the wrong library.